# Thread loop until a process is running

Tags: c#, loops, process

My questions is a bit generic, because I'm still trying to understand how to correctly implement that, however, given I have this code:

```
class Class1
{
    public static void Something()
    {
        if (a)
        {
            //do something in a;
            if (b)
            {
                //do something in b;
                if (c)
                {
                    //do something in c;
                    if (d)
                    {
                        while (Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName").Length > 0)
                        {
                            //execute action
                            return;
                        }

                        if (Process.GetProcessesByName("ProcessName").Length <= 0)
                        {
                            //execute action when the ProcessName is closed
                            ...
                            //start the loop from beginning
                            Something();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What I want to achieve is:
Loop starts with Something(), until it reaches the if (d) condition, then I want to run certain actions in loop until a given process name is running, maybe using a new thread for performance(?). Once the process name is not found anymore, I want to do some other actions, and then start again from the beginning. Is that possible?

What would be the best way to achieve that?

Comment: You can get a Process instance if the app is running (check the array length and grab the first element).  Then call the [WaitForExit()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit?view=netcore-3.1) method.  So you can execute code, wait, then execute more code.  Put the whole thing in a `while` loop instead of recursively calling itself.  The only way this wouldn't work is if you need to REPEATEDLY take an action while the app is open.  If so, HOW OFTEN does that need to happen?

Comment: Another thing you can do is set the EnableRaisingEvents property to true, the wire up the ProcessExited event.

Comment: @Idle_Mind The purpose of this project is an AI which has to be able to start and play a game from within it's launcher, so basically, it launches the game from the launcher, and then starts playing the game, when the game closes, it returns to the launcher, and it has to start again on indefinite loop until shutdown. The only part I'm missing is the actual loop, I can't seem to find a proper way

Comment: That's even better, then, as you already have a Process instance then right (since you launched it yourself)? Wire up that ProcessExited event so you know when it closes.  Then you can just run your loop without needing to check it it's closed or not.  Your code will be broken into two different methods: (1) The Loop and (2) ProcessExited Handler.  You can toggle a flag in the event handler so that the loop knows when the app has closed.

Comment: @Idle_Mind I'm actually not understanding, the process i'm opening is the bot one, then the bot opens the game process (which is the one to monitor). Maybe you can give me an example? thanks tho

Comment: Can we run a,b,c,d before the external process is running?... or should you detect it first, then run them?

Comment: @Idle_Mind a, b, c and d are executed before the external process is started, inside d it starts the process and executes the actions for the opened external process, it also detects the closing, executes post-closure actions and restart from beginning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is quite what you're after...but it ~might~ be a good start?

```
class Class1
{
    private static bool a=true, b=true, c=true;

    private static bool d()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Launching Notepad");
        Process P = Process.Start("notepad");
        Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Notepad");
        P.WaitForInputIdle();
        Console.WriteLine("Notepad is ready!");
        return true;
    }

    public static void Something()
    {

        while (true) // not sure how/when this exits
        {
            if (a)
            {
                //do something in a;
                if (b)
                {
                    //do something in b;
                    if (c)
                    {
                        //do something in c;
                        if (d())
                        {
                            // we'll assume after "d", the process has started
                            Process P = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad").FirstOrDefault();
                            if (P != null)
                            {
                                P.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                                P.Exited += (s, e) => {
                                    //execute action when the ProcessName is closed
                                    Console.WriteLine("Notepad closed.");
                                };

                                // execute action here?
                                Console.WriteLine("Action before loop.");

                                int counter = 1;
                                while (!P.HasExited)
                                {
                                    // execute action or here?
                                    Console.WriteLine("Waiting for Notepad to close: " + counter.ToString());
                                    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); // check every second?
                                    counter++;
                                }                                                                        
                            }

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    }

}
```

Is this running in a WinForms app?  Console app?  Something else?...

Comment: It isnt exactly what I need, as the content of "d" has to be in loop over and over until the external process is running, as "d" is the bot executing actions inside the external process (click there, go there, do that, do this, etc), and that is done using pixel search.

Comment: ah nevermind, i haven't seen the while. so basically putting everything inside that while(!P.HasExited) should execute all actions in loop as far as the process is running, right? is there also a way to actually handle if the process crashed/freezed/hanged?

Comment: There's really no good way to know if a program has crashed unless it periodically does "something" you can check for (like write to a log file, or ping an address, etc).  You could set a time limit and `.Kill()` or `.CloseMainWindow()`.